# system.outofmemoryexception swashbuckle.aspnetcore

Tags: asp.net-core, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I am having this issue when I am dealing with Geometry datatypes when I change the property to string everything works like a charm. Below you may see that I used schema filter to remove Ignored data member , and document filter to remove anything related to nettopology.

Property Name = GeoPoly

Swagger Config Class

---

```
    public static IServiceCollection AddSwaggerModule(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v2", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "Test API", Version = "0.0.1" });
            c.SchemaFilter<MySwaggerSchemaFilter>();
            c.DocumentFilter<RemoveBogusDefinitionsDocumentFilter>();
            c.ResolveConflictingActions(x => x.First());
        });

        return services;
    }

    public static IApplicationBuilder UseApplicationSwagger(this IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseSwagger(c =>
        {
            c.RouteTemplate = "{documentName}/api-docs";
        });
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerEndpoint("/v2/api-docs", "Test API");
        });
        return app;
    }
}
public class MySwaggerSchemaFilter : Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.ISchemaFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiSchema schema, SchemaFilterContext context)
    {
        if (schema?.Properties == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        var ignoreDataMemberProperties = context.Type.GetProperties()
            .Where(t => t.GetCustomAttribute<IgnoreDataMemberAttribute>() != null);

        foreach (var ignoreDataMemberProperty in ignoreDataMemberProperties)
        {
            var propertyToHide = schema.Properties.Keys
                .SingleOrDefault(x => x.ToLower() == ignoreDataMemberProperty.Name.ToLower());

            if (propertyToHide != null)
            {
                schema.Properties.Remove(propertyToHide);
            }
        }
    }
}

public class RemoveBogusDefinitionsDocumentFilter : Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.IDocumentFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiDocument swaggerDoc, DocumentFilterContext context)
    {
        swaggerDoc.Components.Schemas.Remove("Districts");
        swaggerDoc.Components.Schemas.Remove("Geometry");
        swaggerDoc.Components.Schemas.Remove("CoordinateSequenceFactory");
        swaggerDoc.Components.Schemas.Remove("GeometryOverlay");
        swaggerDoc.Components.Schemas.Remove("NtsGeometryServices");
        swaggerDoc.Components.Schemas.Remove("CoordinateEqualityComparer");
        swaggerDoc.Components.Schemas.Remove("NtsGeometryServices");
        swaggerDoc.Components.Schemas.Remove("GeometryFactory");
        swaggerDoc.Components.Schemas.Remove("OgcGeometryType");
        swaggerDoc.Components.Schemas.Remove("Coordinate");
        swaggerDoc.Components.Schemas.Remove("Point");
    }
}
```

### Entity Class

```
public class Districts : BaseEntity<long>
{
    public string DistrictsDesc { get; set; }
    public string DistrictsDescAr { get; set; }

    [IgnoreDataMember]
    [Column(TypeName = "geometry")]
    public Geometry GeoPoly { get;  set; }
    public IList<Records> Records { get; set; } = new List<Records>();
    public long? RegionsId { get; set; }
    public Regions Regions { get; set; }

    public long? CitiesId { get; set; }
    public Cities Cities { get; set; }

   
}
```

Is there a way to stop swashbuckle gen from dealing with datatypes other than documents filter ?

Comment: `Geometry` is a database type. Neither Swagger not ASP.NET Core know what to do with it. *Don't* use the same class for your database entities and API payload. If you use two separate types you won't have to filter anything

Comment: Thanks for your reply. actually, I am considering moving all Geometry processes as  stored procedures.